# Find distinct values in two tables using most recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access

Thanks in advance for the help!

I have two tables, Header and Detail, in which I need to combine and select the most recent receipt of an item. What is the best way to write a query to accomplish this?

Header Table data:

```
HEADER_PO_NUM   HEADER_VENDOR_NAME  HEADER_ORDER_DATE
1               VENDOR A            1/1/2017
2               VENDOR A            2/1/2017
3               VENDOR B            1/15/2017
4               VENDOR B            2/15/2017
5               VENDOR C            1/25/2017
6               VENDOR C            2/25/2017
```

Detail Table data:

```
DETAIL_PO_NUM   DETAIL_ITEM_NUM   DETAIL_ITEM_DESC    DETAIL_PURCH_QTY  DETAIL_RECD_QTY   DETAIL_RECD_DATE
1               ABC               Bobbles             100               100               3/1/2017
2               ABC               Bobbles             300               300               3/15/2017
1               DEF               Knick Knacks        500               500               3/1/2017
2               DEF               Knick Knacks        5402              5402              3/15/2017
3               GHI               Doo Dads            392               392               3/1/2017
4               GHI               Doo Dads            3                 3                 3/15/2017
3               JKL               Hoozits             939               939               3/1/2017
4               JKL               Hoozits             31                31                3/15/2017
5               MNO               Whatsitz            392               392               4/1/2017
6               MNO               Whatsitz            294               294               4/25/2017
5               PQR               Dinglehopper        32                32                4/1/2017
6               PRQ               Dinglehopper        293               293               4/25/2017
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
DETAIL_PO_NUM   DETAIL_ITEM_NUM   DETAIL_ITEM_DESC    DETAIL_PURCH_QTY  DETAIL_RECD_QTY   DETAIL_RECD_DATE     HEADER_VENDOR_NAME
2               ABC               Bobbles             300               300               3/15/2017            VENDOR A
2               DEF               Knick Knacks        5402              5402              3/15/2017            VENDOR A
4               GHI               Doo Dads            3                 3                 3/15/2017            VENDOR B
4               JKL               Hoozits             31                31                3/15/2017            VENDOR B
6               MNO               Whatsitz            294               294               4/25/2017            VENDOR C
6               PRQ               Dinglehopper        293               293               4/25/2017            VENDOR C
```

I am able to get it narrowed down by `DETAIL_ITEM_NUM` and `DETAIL_RECD_DATE`, but not able to include the other columns using the following Access SQL query:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT DETAIL.DETAIL_ITEM_NUM,
  Max(DETAIL.DETAIL_RECD_DATE) AS MaxOfDETAIL_RECD_DATE
FROM HEADER 
INNER JOIN 
  DETAIL ON HEADER.HEADER_PO_NUM = DETAIL.DETAIL_PO_NUM
GROUP BY DETAIL.DETAIL_ITEM_NUM;
```

I have searched, reviewed, and tried several answers (over the past few days), but just can't seem to get them to work.

I appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first get the most recent orders from the details table. If that's what you are looking for, then please mark the answer as correct by selecting it on the left next to counter at the beginning of the answer. And if it's not what you are looking for, then please add a comment with further requirements.
We will use the detail table twice, named a and b respectively.

For the moment we can forget about the join with the header table and focus on the detail table. We will work with mainly with the two columns item_num, which can have the same value multiple times, and the column recd_date, which records the date and which we will assume to have unique dates for each group of ite_num's.

Assume we have a item_num value in a variable abc, for example with the value "ABC" (see lines 1 and 2 in the detail table).

We can select the most recent row by selecting precisely one row from all the rows with this item_num "ABC" by ordering them by recorded date descending.

```
SELECT TOP 1 d.*
FROM detail AS d
WHERE d.detail_item_num = "ABC"  -- or some variable's value like abc in general
ORDER BY d.detail_recd_date DESC  -- most recent row please
```

Now we apply this to all rows in the detail table. For each of the rows, use the current row's group identifying column `detail_item_num` to find all rows of the group in the inner `SELECT` query, then get the most recent one.

Or in other words. For each row, decide if it should appear in the result by checking if `a.detail_po_num` of this current row is the same as the effectively unique `b.detail_po_num` of the most recent row in the group.
This should give you the set of rows which are most recent, one per group.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM detail AS a
WHERE a.detail_po_num = (  -- if = does not work, go with IN
  SELECT TOP 1 detail_po_num   -- this should allow =, but use IN in general (for TOP 3, i.e.)
  FROM detail AS b
  WHERE a.detail_item_num = b.detail_item_num  -- rows in same group only
  ORDER BY b.detail_recd_date DESC, b.detail_po_num DESC  -- po_num tie breaker
);
```

By effectively unique, I mean my assumption that the combination of detail columns (detail_item_num, detail_recd_date, detail_po_num) is UNIQUE.
If you assume the date to be unique for every group identified by the same value item_num, then (detail_item_num, detail_po_num) could also be UNIQUE.

The second part of the `ORDER BY` clause is used as a tie breaker, which only fires in the case that not all `recd_date`'s are unique. If you have no tie breaker, the DBMS is free to return different results for the same query at different times. The second part `b.detail_item_num DESC` favors the highest `po_num` in this case.

If this works, then you can join now, just like you did above. Just use the given name `a`, which was given to the outer detail table.

Oh, and it's possible that there is a typo in the query, because I don't have MS Access installed and wrote this without letting it run. Besides I didn't want to form your data into `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements. So, the query is unchecked.

Comment: Typo in the query: detail_po_num is tie breaker, not detail_item_num, which is the same xD

Comment: Did you know that marking the answer as correct and upvoting it are two different things? And checking the mark next to the points to accept the answer gives not only me, but also you points? Come on, gimme those juicy points - it took ages to write up such a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you Flutter!